# i want to make function for 6 edittext boxes in android which includes all properties of edittext so that i can just simply call function

Tags: java, android

i have 6 edittext boxes i want to make a function for that 6 edittext boxes so that i can simply call that function instead of defining edittext boxes all the times. here is d code of edittext boxes ....

```
TableLayout t1=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_layout01);
                TableRow tr1=new TableRow(inventory.this);
                tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                EditText ed6=new EditText(inventory.this);
                ed6.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                ed6.setText("1");

                tr1.addView(ed6);

                EditText ed7=new EditText(inventory.this);
                ed7.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                ed7.setText("2");

                tr1.addView(ed7);

                EditText ed8=new EditText(inventory.this);
                ed8.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                ed8.setText("3");

                tr1.addView(ed8);.............(3 more edittext same like these)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for loop and write edittext adding to tr1 code in that loop
like

```
 for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
TableRow tr1=new TableRow(this);
    EditText ed7=new EditText(inventory.this); 
      ed7.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);     
       String s=new Integer(i).toString();      //convert the integer into String   
       ed7.setText(s); 
tr1.addView(ed7);
 <TableLayoutName>.addview(tr1);
    }
```